# Swift NumberFormatter if value is 0 return empty string

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, numberformatter

I have the following code:

```
struct Food {
    var name: String
    var energy: Float = 0
    var water: Float = 0
}
```

```
struct FoodItemView: View {
    
    @State var newFoodItem = Food(name: "")
    private var numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Basics").fontWeight(.bold)) {
                TextField("Name", text: $newFoodItem.name)
                TextField("Energy (C)", value: $newFoodItem.energy, formatter: numberFormatter)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                TextField("Water (g)", value: $newFoodItem.water, formatter: numberFormatter)
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make it so that, the value displayed in my TextFields would be an empty string if the bound value is 0, rather than explicitly displaying the 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set  `.zeroSymbol` property of `NumberFormatter`.

```
struct FoodItemView: View {
    
    @State var newFoodItem = Food(name: "")
    private var numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    
    init() {
        numberFormatter.zeroSymbol = "" //<< Here
    }

// Other Code
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! It's really cool that there is an API for that.